# Can I copy shape keys from one model to another in separate files?

Tags: modeling, rigging, shape-keys

I'm setting up model bases and don't want to do all the shape keys all over again. I have them all done for the female base and want to copy them over to the male base. They have pretty similar vertex structures, but are in different .blend files. Is there any way to copy them over? Or do I have to make them again?

Comment: you will need to import the object then use "transfer shape key"